# Specify vim filetype on command line

Tags: vim

I've been working with a lot of C++ files that have no extensions and it's too annoying to have to type `:set ft=cpp` every time I open them, so I'm mostly just working without syntax highlighting. Is there a way to tell vim the file type in the command line? Something like:

```
$ vim --ft=cpp file_name
```

Comment: add set ft=cpp to your ~/.vimrc  but in this way, all your file opened will be treated as cpp file.

Comment: @LeeHoYo it's not the only filetype I work with

Comment: @LeeHoYo - that would set if for every file. OP wants to set it when opening specific files.

Comment: eh... maybe there is another way to do that. alias vimcpp="vim --ft=cpp "

Comment: @LeeHoYo - that would work, but then you would need a different alias for each filetype. Expanding on your suggestion, an alternative could be `alias vimft="vim --ft="`. Then you could just execute vim as `vimft cpp`.

Comment: You can set file type even after opening any file, at any time 

Comment: @SibiCoder - OP specifically mentions that in the post body.

Comment: Add this to the end of your file: `// vim: ft=cpp`. Read `:h modeline` for details.

Comment: @SatoKatsura - that's a cool little trick! I'm pretty sure it'll annoy all the members of the team that don't use vim though.. Probably wouldn't pass my code review either :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `-c` option when launching vim to execute commands after the first file has been read.

For your situation, you can simply use the standard `set filetype` command -

```
vim -c 'set filetype=javascript'
```

You could also use `--cmd` to execute the command *after* the first file is loaded.

Lifted from the vim man pages:

```
   -c {command}
               {command} will be executed after the first file has been read.  {command} is interpreted as an Ex command.  If the {command} contains spaces it must be enclosed in double quotes (this depends on  the  shell  that  is  used).
               Example: Vim "+set si" main.c
               Note: You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" commands.

   --cmd {command}
               Like using "-c", but the command is executed just before processing any vimrc file.  You can use up to 10 of these commands, independently from "-c" commands.
```